# PHP Won't Send Mail using mail.php

Tags: php

i am sending a mail using php mail file.but i am getting error.this is my code
and error

`Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl"` `- did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?` `(code: -1, response: )]`

```
<?php
@require_once "Mail.php";

$from = 'email';
$to = 'email';

 1. List item

$subject = 'Hi!';


$headers = array(

    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject,
    'from' => $from 
);

$smtp = @Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'email',
        'password' => 'password'
    ));

$mail = @$smtp->send($to, $headers);

if (@PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
} else {
    echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
}

?>
```

this all error

`Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\pear\Net\SMTP.php on line 491`

`Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\pear\Net\SMTP.php on line 265`

`Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::raiseError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\pear\Net\SMTP.php on line 267`

Comment: The strict errors do not prevent the code from working, you can disable them, setting your error_reporting in php.ini to to E_ALL & ~E_STRICT

Comment: what should `Mail.php` contain?

Comment: I'm sure that if you would add just one more `@` (STFU operator) it will work.

Comment: it seems that your php isn't configured to use SSL, contact your provider, or edit your `php.ini` (`/etc/php.ini`) and enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that your php isn't configured to use SSL, contact your provider, or edit your `php.ini` (`/etc/php.ini`) and enable it.

Comment: aqctualy i have to comment out extension=php_openssl.dll this line in php.ini

Comment: @RimjhimRatnani I've changed my answer to the comment I've made previously, that turned out to be the solution. Can you please mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
include("Mail.php"); 

/* mail setup recipients, subject etc */ 
$recipients = "feedback@yourdot.com"; 
$headers["From"] = "user@somewhere.com"; 
$headers["To"] = "feedback@yourdot.com"; 
$headers["Subject"] = "User feedback"; 

$mailmsg = "Hello, This is a test."; 

/* SMTP server name, port, user/passwd */ 
$smtpinfo["host"] = "smtp.mycorp.com"; 
$smtpinfo["port"] = "25"; 
$smtpinfo["auth"] = true; 
$smtpinfo["username"] = "smtpusername"; 
$smtpinfo["password"] = "smtpPassword"; 

/* Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method */ 
$mail_object =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo); 

/* Ok send mail */ 
$mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $mailmsg); 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

actually didn't  comment out extension=php_openssl.dll line  in php.ini
that is only problem in my code